# Convert scala list to Json object

Tags: json, list, scala

I want to convert a scala list of strings, List[String], to an Json object.

For each string in my list I want to add it to my Json object.

So that it would look like something like this:

```
{
 "names":[
  {
    "Bob",
    "Andrea",
    "Mike",
    "Lisa"
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I create an json object looking like this, from my list of strings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To directly answer your question, a very simplistic and hacky way to do it:

```
val start = """"{"names":[{"""
val end = """}]}"""
val json = mylist.mkString(start, ",", end)
```

However, what you almost certainly want to do is pick one of the many JSON libraries out there: [play-json](http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/) gets some good comments, as does [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/). At the worst, you could just grab a simple JSON library for Java and use that.

Comment: val start = """"{"names":[{""""
val end = """"}]}"""
val json = mylist.mkString(start, """","""", end)

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm familiar with lift-json, I'll show you how to do it with that library.

```
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.Printer._
import net.liftweb.json.JObject

val json: JObject = "names" -> List("Bob", "Andrea", "Mike", "Lisa")

println(json)
println(pretty(render(json)))
```

The `names -> List(...)` expression is implicitly converted by the JsonDSL, since I specified that I wanted it to result in a `JObject`, so now `json` is the in-memory model of the json data you wanted.

`pretty` comes from the `Printer` object, and `render` comes from the `JsonAST` object. Combined, they create a `String` representation of your data, which looks like

```
{
  "names":["Bob","Andrea","Mike","Lisa"]
}
```

Be sure to check out the [lift documentation](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/), where you'll likely find answers to any further questions about lift's json support.